# Oracle SQL: Merge rows into single row

Tags: sql, oracle

How to merge rows into single row in SQL?

ex: `SELECT distinct studentID, studentName, MathGrade, SciGrade from vStudentGrade;`

output:

```
   StudentID       studentName        MathGrade         SciGrade
    1               Zed                89
    1               Zed                                  98
```

desired output:

```
  StudentID        studentName        MatheGrade         SciGrade
   1                Zed                89                 98
```

Comment: hope below link will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=merge+rows+in+one+row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder what criteria you're using to group them. I'm assuming there always be NULL values and a number... because that matches de example, but more detail would be better!

```
SELECT studentID, studentName, max(MathGrade), max(SciGrade) from vStudentGrade
group by studentID, studentName, MathGrade, SciGrade
```

Hope this helps or guide you to a solution :)

Comment: Welcome. If this solved the problem don't forget to mark the question as answered